# tkinter not installed properly in Anaconda Python 2.7 Win64

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, anaconda, win64

I believe from this [post](https://community.activestate.com/node/19090) that this is not an uncommon issue with `tkinter` and new downloads of `Python 2.7` (after re-downloading from 2016 on). I am using the Anaconda 2.7 for win64 on a Windows 7 machine. The filepaths seem almost identical to what is described [here](https://community.activestate.com/node/19090), except for "Anaconda2" instead of "Python27"; the "tcl" folder is in it's own directory in C:/Users/user:2312900/tcl and not in the "lib" directory.

Is there any way to fix this for Anaconda? That I tried what was described in the post, but it didn't work for me.

Is there any way to manually install a 64bit python 2.7 compatible wheel for tkinter? Does anyone know of any other packages to make simple GUI's with Python if this is an irreconcilable issue with the Annaconda distribution. I have a lot of other packages that were painfully installed that I do not want to use something else.

Comment: you can still use wxWidgets if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Anaconda2 64bit and tkinter does indeed work, as I use it frequently. It might be something simple: can you import the package into your program? Try `import Tkinter` instead, i.e. with a capital 'T'.

Comment: I probably should have clarified but I have also tried all possible incantations of 'import Tkinter' possible between both 'pip' and 'conda'. I also downloaded the zip file of the code and tried to install with no success.

Comment: @user2312900 Uninstall anaconda with windows, make sure you delete any files left over from the uninstallation. When you install Anaconda again, using the package installer from https://www.continuum.io/downloads , make sure you tick the "install for all users" option when prompted. Next you should tick the  `Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable` check box, and the same with the `Register Anaconda as my default Python 2.7` checkbox, keep both of them as your preferred options. Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have user on your Windows called "`user:2312900`"? Python (and some other programs) don't like paths with special characters like colon ":". Try to install all your needed programs (Python, Tkinter, etc) in the path without special characters **and** without spaces " ".

For example: `c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\` or `c:\Python27\`